# Jquery plugin with Scala

Tags: jquery, scala.js, scalajs-react

Any one knows how to use a jquery plugin [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) in scala js code.

Scala.js has library which wrapped a jquery, I want to use similar statitically type code for jquery plugin

finally I want to create a react component for multiselect list out of this two.
Any alternative way to is also welcom

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably going to need to write a Scala.js facade for the bootstrap-multiselect plugin. This isn't rocket science, but it'll be a bit of work. [Here is a detailed article on how to do it.](https://www.querki.net/u/jducoeur/scala-notes/#!Creating-a-Scalajs-Facade-for-a-jQuery-Widget)

Comment: Thanks Justin, Thanks looks exactly what I was looking for. cheers